# How can I disable grid line on Unity project>

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I did an android game in unity but I see a square grid line on the screen of project, followed by multiple grey grid lines.

Im still new to unity so I dont know how to disable it could you please help me. Thanks :)

Comment: if this is in the editor thats fine, its supposed to be like that, if its when you hit play, it may depend on what gizmos and stuff you have

Comment: alright thanks @BugFinder

Comment: This is most certainly about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript]

Answer (score 3):

Set Grid Opacity is zero. (Hide)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As @BugFinder says, the grid is not output from the device.

However, if you do not want the grid to be visible, you can turn off the 'Show Grid' option by clicking on the Gizmos drop-down menu in the Scene screen.

Answer (score 1):

One can change the grid settings from the Grid like symbol with a 'y' in it in the same line as gizmos. Unity 2020.1.

Answer (score 0):

In 2019+ there is a little grid icon with a y that toggles this on the same bar as the gizmos button, but not underneath its dropdown.

Comment: Try to make more obvious that you are actually trying to answer the question - and only that. It might have saved you from downvotes.